# Why isn't for loop assigning the correct value based on the conditional statements in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, iteration

I have a block of code where I'm trying to write a for loop to iterate through all the players in a data frame and assign a Years Pro where the value is Year - Draft Years. Glen Rice has a son who was drafted in 2013 but the years he played were around 2003-2005 so I want to assign him the proper draft year. I didn't want to interfere with his son's stats so I'm trying to write a for loop if the draft year is greater than the year it should change the draft year. Any ideas of why the for loop isn't working?

Thanks in advance for the help

```
for (Player in df2){

if ((df2$Player == "Glen Rice")&&(df2$Draft_Year > df2$Year)){ 
df2$Draft_Year <- 1989}


}
```

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example, but it looks like you are using the `for (... in ...)` incorrectly.  In this case, a for loop might not be necessary, but first provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Hard to know without a reproducible example, but you probably want `df2$Draft_Year[df2$Player == 'Glen Rice' & df2$Draft_Year > df2$Year,] <- 1989`

Comment: && only looks at the first element

Comment: @Ryan, why not use the vectorized `ifelse`: `df2$Draft_Year <- ifelse(df2$Player == 'Glen Rice' & df2$Draft_Year > df2$Year, 1989, df2$Draft_Year)`

Comment: @Parfait Assignment to a vector subsetted with `[]` is also a vectorized operation. Actually, using `ifelse` adds a little overhead because you're also reassigning some elements to their original value. Using `[]` only assigns to the elements meeting the condition.

Comment: @Ryan - correct!